# Interface and Inheritance compile time error

Tags: java, object, inheritance, methods, interface

I have written a short program that uses inheritances and interface relationships to calculate the area and the perimeter of user selected shapes.  I receive a compile time error when I attempt to compile the following classes.

**Class Square**

```
 public class Square extends Quadrilateral
        {

        double side1 =this.side1; 
        double side2 = this.side2; 
        double perimeter = this.perimeter; 
        double area = this.area; 

        Square(double instanceSide1, double instanceSide2) {
        side1 = instanceSide1;
        side2 = instanceSide2;
        }

        @Override
        public double area() 
        {
        area = side1 *side2;
        return area;
        }

        @Override
        public double perimeter() //math equation for determing perimeter
        {
        this.perimeter = (side1 * 2) + (side2 * 2) ;
        return perimeter;
        }
        }
```

**Here is my Quad class**

```
    public abstract class Quadrilateral implements Polygon{
    }
```

**Here is the Polygon Class**

```
    public interface Polygon {
    abstract void area();
    abstract void perimeter();    
    }
```

**Here is the Tester Class** that I've built to run the code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) //Constructor initalizing main class
    {
    int numberSides;
    int length;
    int base;

    Scanner sides = new Scanner(System.in); //Initializing Scanner Class


     /**
     * Do/while loop for selecting a 3 or 4 sided object
     */
    do 
    {
        System.out.println("Do you want a 3 or 4 sided shape? (Type either "
                + "3 or 4).");

        numberSides = sides.nextInt();

    } while (numberSides < 3 || numberSides > 4);

    if (numberSides == 3) {
        System.out.println("How long are the sides that are the same lenth?");
        length = sides.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How wide is the base? (whole numbers");
        base = sides.nextInt();
        IsoscelesTriangle Isoc = new IsoscelesTriangle(length, base);
        System.out.println("The area of the isocolese triangle is: " + Isoc.area());
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the isocolese triangle is: " + Isoc.perimeter());
    } else {
        System.out.println("How long are the sides are the same?");
        length = sides.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How wide is the base?");
        base = sides.nextInt();

        if (length == base) {
            Square Quad = new Square(length, base);
            System.out.println("The area of the square is: " + Quad.area());
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the square is: " + Quad.perimeter());
        } else {
            Rectangle Quad = new Rectangle(length, base);
            System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is: " + Quad.area());
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the rectangle is: " + Quad.perimeter());
        }
        }
     }

     }
```

Comment: Please what's your error message? And what line(s) causes it?

Comment: I am getting the following:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at PolygonTester.main(PolygonTester.java:46) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Triangle is not abstract and does not override abstract method perimeter() in Polygon at Triangle.<clinit>(Triangle.java:11)

Comment: Please always post critical information in your question itself, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class that implements the interface does not have methods that matches the interface. The interface's methods return void, while the class returns double. They must match exactly, and probably it is the class that's right and the interface that's wrong -- change the interface method declarations to return double.

In the future, you will want to post all error / exception messages if you have a question about them. It will help us save time and get you better answers.

Comment: I have corrected the return type in the interface class, but I'm getting a compiletime error.  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at polygonTester.main(PolygonTester.java:46) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Triangle is not abstract and does not override abstract method perimeter() in Polygon at Triangle.<clinit>(Triangle.java:11)

Comment: I modified the triangle class to abstract class and it does compile!

Comment: @BNats: Nope, wrong fix. The correct solution is to not make it abstract (you will need to use this class, right? And you can't directly construct an abstract class) but instead give it a proper `perimeter()` method.